# Using Stash variable inside of channel entries loop

Tags: stash

So, I have a scenario where I'm setting a Stash variable based on a query string being passed. I'm using Mo' Variables to get the $_GET values.

```
// Query string: /?c1=74&c2=81

{exp:ifelse parse="inward" parse_tags="yes"}
{if get:c1}
  {exp:stash:set name="active_cat" parse_tags="yes"}{get:c1}{/exp:stash:set}
  {/if}

  {if get:c2}
  {exp:stash:set name="active_cat" parse_tags="yes"}{get:c2}{/exp:stash:set}
  {/if}

  {if get:c3}
  {exp:stash:set name="active_cat" parse_tags="yes"}{get:c3}{/exp:stash:set}
  {/if}

  {if get:c4}
  {exp:stash:set name="active_cat" parse_tags="yes"}{get:c4}{/exp:stash:set}
  {/if}
{/exp:ifelse}

Works directly: {exp:stash:get name="c2" dynamic="yes"}<br> // outputs 81
Stash Variable works: {exp:stash:get name="active_cat" process="end"} // outputs 81

{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="{stash:_channel}" 
    category="{exp:stash:get name='active_cat' process='end'}"
    dynamic="no" 
    orderby="title" 
    sort="asc" 
    limit="10" 
    parse="inward"
    status="{stash:_status}"
    disable="member_data|pagination"
}
    <li><a href="{structure:page_url_for:{entry_id}}">{stash:_channel} - {stash:_status} - {title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Basically, it assigns a Stash variable 'active_cat' to c1, c2, etc. If a "c4" exists though, it overwrites that variable with the new value.

It works outside of the channel entries loop, but isn't being passed into the channel entries loop. This is in a Stash embed and there are 2 other variables passed into the loop correctly from the parent template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that I have to wrap the channel entries tag pair inside of {exp:stash:parse process="end"}, and then remove the process='end' from the active_cat tag being passed as a parameter.

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="{stash:_channel}" 
    category="{exp:stash:active_cat}"
    dynamic="no" 
    orderby="title" 
    sort="asc" 
    limit="10" 
    parse="inward"
    status="{stash:_status}"
    disable="member_data|pagination"
}
    <li><a href="{structure:page_url_for:{entry_id}}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```